# Strange PowerShell issue, ?scoping?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a Function that filters out duplicate entries from a DataTable. My code works fine but only if lines:3-4 are NOT in comment. I tried changing default scope of $tbl1 variable to global but it didn't help.

What am I doing doing? Code is below.

```
Function RemoveDuplicates
{
    #$tbl1 | export-csv ".\tmp.csv"   #Code works perfectly when you uncomment these two lines.
    #$tbl1 = import-csv ".\tmp.csv"   #

    $t_tbl = $tbl1 | Sort-Object -Property Prop3 -Unique
    $duplicates = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $tbl1 -DifferenceObject $t_tbl -Property Prop3
    #$duplicates

    write-host "tbl1 count: $($tbl1.Rows.Count)"
    write-host "t_tbl count: $($t_tbl.Count)"
    write-host "duplicates count: $(@($duplicates).Count)"

    write-host "Found $($tbl1.Rows.Count) entries. $($t_tbl.Count) entries have unique Prop3. Duplicates: $(@($duplicates).count)"
}
    $tbl1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $col1 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn Prop1,([string])
    $col2 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn Prop2,([string])
    $col3 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn Prop3,([string])
    $tbl1.Columns.Add($col1)
    $tbl1.Columns.Add($col2)
    $tbl1.Columns.Add($col3)

    $row = $tbl1.NewRow()
            $row.Prop1 = "Jane"
            $row.Prop2 = "Doe"
            $row.Prop3 = "jane.doe@domain.local"
        $tbl1.Rows.Add($row)
    $row = $tbl1.NewRow()
            $row.Prop1 = "Jack"
            $row.Prop2 = "Awesome"
            $row.Prop3 = "jane.doe@domain.local"
        $tbl1.Rows.Add($row)
    $row = $tbl1.NewRow()
            $row.Prop1 = "Julia"
            $row.Prop2 = "Whatever"
            $row.Prop3 = "test@domain.local"
        $tbl1.Rows.Add($row)
    $row = $tbl1.NewRow()
            $row.Prop1 = "Mr"
            $row.Prop2 = "ScriptGuy!"
            $row.Prop3 = "scriptguy@domain.local"
        $tbl1.Rows.Add($row)
    $row = $tbl1.NewRow()
            $row.Prop1 = "Mrs"
            $row.Prop2 = "ScriptLady!"
            $row.Prop3 = "scriptlady@domain.local"
        $tbl1.Rows.Add($row)

    RemoveDuplicates
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it has nothing to do with scope.  It has everything to do with data types.

It can be frustrating:

Compare-Object takes two arrays and enumerates through them both to find items that are different.  As a test, lets see how PowerShell enumerates `$tbl1`.  The `foreach` keyword acts much the same as parameter parsing in regards to objects and arrays.

```
foreach($row in $tbl1) { $_ }
```

The output is blank.  This is because it is seen as a single object, and not as a collection.
PowerShell cmdlet parameter parsing does not enumerate over a default collection variable. However, if we push the table through the pipeline,

```
$tbl1 | % { $_ }
```

We get the data for each row:

```
Prop1                                                       Prop2                                                      Prop3                                                     
-----                                                       -----                                                      -----                                                     
Jane                                                        Doe                                                        jane.doe@domain.local                                     
Jack                                                        Awesome                                                    jane.doe@domain.local                                     
Julia                                                       Whatever                                                   test@domain.local                                         
Mr                                                          ScriptGuy!                                                 scriptguy@domain.local                                    
Mrs                                                         ScriptLady!                                                scriptlady@domain.local
```

It then follows, that the line: `$t_tbl = $tbl1 | Sort-Object -Property Prop3 -Unique` would create a array of objects output from the Sort object command, and in fact, if we execute the following: `$t_tbl.GetType().FullName`; $*tbl | Select-Object -First 1 | % { $*.GetType().FullName }, we see that it is a `System.Object[]` (an array) where each item is a `System.Data.DataRow` instance.  `$tbl1` however is a `System.Data.DataTable` instance, not an array.

So, when `Compare-Object` does it's work, it is comparing an array of datarows against a singular datatable. Look at the contents of `$duplicates` with that in mind, when the lines are commented out.

```
# Output of Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $tbl1 -DifferenceObject $t_tbl -Property Prop3
Prop3                   SideIndicator
-----                   -------------
jane.doe@domain.local   =>           
scriptguy@domain.local  =>           
scriptlady@domain.local =>           
test@domain.local       =>           
                        <=
```

The parameters `ReferenceObject` and `DifferenceObject` are expecting arrays.  While we are passing `DifferenceObject` an array, we are passing `ReferenceObject` a single value, which the cmdlet treats as an array of size 1.

The DataTable does not have a `Prop3` to compare.

When you uncomment the lines, you pull the content of the CSV file back in, you are not getting a DataTable object.  You are getting an array of `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` instances with member properties based on the columns in the CSV file.  In this case, Compare-Object has two arrays to compare now, both with objects that have a Prop3 property.

If all you need to do is get the unique values for one column in a data table, try this:

```
$tbl1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Prop3 | Get-Unique
```

Comment: FinalizedFrustration,